# Why is \printbibliography[keyword=key1] not working as expected?

Tags: bibtex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=ynt,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\nocite{*}
\subsection*{Conference Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=none, resetnumbers,keyword={key1}]

\subsection*{Conference Abstracts}
\printbibliography[heading=none, resetnumbers,notkeyword={key1}]

\end{document}
```

with citations

```
@inproceedings{citation1,
    author = "last1 , First1",
    title = "title1",
    booktitle = "book1",
    pages = "0333",
    year = "2022",
    keyword="key1"
}

@inproceedings{citation2,
    author = "Last2, First2",
    title = "title2",
    booktitle = "book2",
    pages = "0045",
    year = "2022"
}
```

Does not have the expected output. The keyword is not recognized at all. Thus, the first \printbibliography prints nothing and  the second prints both. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The key in the .bib file should be `keywords`, not `keyword`. You can put multiple keywords here, hence the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key in the .bib file should be `keywords`, not `keyword`. You can put multiple keywords here, hence the name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@inproceedings{citation1,
    author = "last1 , First1",
    title = "title1",
    booktitle = "book1",
    pages = "0333",
    year = "2022",
    keywords = "key1"
}

@inproceedings{citation2,
    author = "Last2, First2",
    title = "title2",
    booktitle = "book2",
    pages = "0045",
    year = "2022"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    sorting=ynt,
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\nocite{*}

\subsection*{Conference Articles}
\printbibliography[
    heading=none, 
    resetnumbers,
    keyword={key1}
]

\subsection*{Conference Abstracts}
\printbibliography[
    heading=none, 
    resetnumbers,
    notkeyword={key1}
]

\end{document}
```

[image]